# ¿Cómo eliminar una carpeta de este tipo y que no está vacia en Linux?

Tags: linux

¿Cómo eliminar carpeta de este tipo `".carpeta"` y que no está vacía.

He utilizado `rmdir --ignore-fail-on-non-empty` pero al parecer que no funciona. La carpeta está en `/home/usuario`.

Comment: ya intestaste con `sudo rm -rf .carpeta`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esas carpetas a las que te refieres son consideradas por Linux como ocultas. Lo mismo sucede con los archivos del tipo `.archivo.txt`.

El comando `rmdir` solo funciona para eliminar carpetas vacías. De hecho, esto se muestra en la ayuda del comando:

```
$ rmdir --help
Usage: rmdir [OPTION]... DIRECTORY...
Remove the DIRECTORY(ies), if they are empty.
..
```

Dice "if they are empty" (si están vacíos).

El flag `--ignore-fail-on-non-empty` no ignora el hecho de que la carpeta esté vacía, lo que hace es simplemente ignorar el mensaje de error:

```
$ rmdir .carpeta
rmdir: failed to remove '.carpeta/': Directory not empty
$ rmdir --ignore-fail-on-non-empty .carpeta
$
```

El mensaje de error ha sido omitido pero la carpeta y su contenido siguen existiendo.

Como menciona Daniel en su comentario, puedes lograrlo usando el comando `rm`. No es necesario usar `sudo` si la carpeta le pertenece a tu usuario. Ahora, el flag `-r` se usa para borrar de manera recursiva, es decir, si dentro de `.carpeta` hay más directorios y archivos entonces estos también serán eliminados. El flag `-f` sirve para forzar la eliminación sin preguntar por confirmación, incluso si está protegido contra escritura:

```
$ rm -rf .carpeta
```

Adiós, carpeta.

Comment: Muy buena explicación, gracias